# Convert mycert.cer root.cer and ca.cer into p12 file with openssl

Tags: openssl, certificate, digital-signatures

I purchase a certificate to sign PDF from a supplier. They delivered 3 files: mycert.cer, ca.cer and root.cer. I need to create a p12 file from it. But i have no success doing this.
I tried:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in mycert.cer -nokeys -out finnal.p12 -certfile ca.cer -certfile root.cer
```

It asks for a export password and it creates the p12 file. Then i tried to use it to sign a PDF using [PortableSigner2](http://portablesigner.sourceforge.net/):

But it gives an error:

```
Position V:0.0 L:0.0 R:0.0
Error reading certificate (no key)
    null
```

I also tried to use the [Portecle](https://sourceforge.net/projects/portecle/) to export to p12. Again does not give any error but when i try to use the p12 to sign, it gives errors.

Anyone can help me doing this task? Thank you.

Comment: You created a PKCS12 file, without privatekey. **Signing requires the privatekey.** The normal process is (1) you generate the privatekey, (2) you extract the publickey in the form of a CSR, (3) you use the CSR to obtain a certificate (plus its chain), (4) you use the privatekey from 1 together with the certs from 3. You failed to tell us about your step 1.

Comment: you are right! I forgot that. I changed the comand to: openssl pkcs12 -export -in mycert.cer -inkey my.key -out finnal.p12 -certfile ca.cer -certfile root.cer, and it work well. Just one doubt: i sign the pdf and check it with pdfsig. All return okay except this: Certificate Validation: Unknown issue with Certificate or corrupted data. Might be something with the root.cer or ca.cer?

Comment: All problems went away when i used jsignpdf. All the details of the signed pdf were crrect. Thank you.